# Using Expo with react-native-skia

Tags: react-native, skia

Does anyone have an example project or a link to react-native-skia actually working with Expo?  Do you have it working with the web?

Answer (score 1):

Great timing! I was struggling with the same thing a few weeks ago, and I finally figured it out.

Have a look: https://github.com/gjtiquia/react-native-web-skia

*Update: June 22, 2023*

Some things to keep in mind:

- Expo does not support Reanimated 3 yet, meaning you can only use Reanimated 2, so that probably means you cannot use the UI thread and all animations will be driven by the JS main thread.
- Remember to follow the web setup for BOTH React Native Skia and Reanimated.
- If you are using the [WithSkiaWeb](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/getting-started/web) component, make sure that this component will only appear in the web app. If the component ever appeared in the native app and you tried to open the the app with Expo Go, it will crash. Using the [Platform module](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/platform-differences/) does not help either. The only way I got it to work was by separating the web and native code using [Platform-specific extensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions). The native app can load the Skia canvas component directly while the web app must load it via the `WithSkiaWeb` component.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll definitely add more helpful details on my answer.